# Style link in a li

Tags: html, css

I have this list in HTML

```
<div id="sideMenu">
    <li class="current_page_parent">
        <a href="#">Category 1</a>
        <ul class="children">
            <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</div>
```

I want to put a background-color to my first link : 'Category 1' without affecting others links

Here's my CSS

```
.current_page_parent li:not(.children) a {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    background-color: #d6205c;
}
```

Comment: correct your DOM to W3C stranded div have child of li, change in to <ul id="sideMenu"> <li>..</li></ul> required.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**`first-of-type`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type) combined with a `>` [**combinator selector**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors)

> The `:first-of-type` CSS pseudo-class represents the first sibling of
>   its type in the list of children of its parent element.
>
> The `>` combinator separates two selectors and matches only those
>   elements matched by the second selector that are direct children of
>   elements matched by the first.

```
li.current_page_parent:first-of-type > a{
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    background-color: #d6205c;
}
```

```css
li.current_page_parent:first-of-type > a {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  background-color: #d6205c;
}
```

```html
<div id="sideMenu">
  <li class="current_page_parent">
    <a href="#">Category 1</a>
    <ul class="children">
      <li><a href="#">Sub</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</div>
```

Comment: You have the wrong selector, OP wanted the `li` (I think :-)

Comment: @Amit - incorrect, the OP states: `I want to put a background-color to my *first link* : Category 1 without put one on others *links*`

Comment: Actually I would rather prefer put a background on my first li, but when I do this, It's all my li with the '.children' inside who takes the background-color

Comment: Simply move the `:first-ot-type` switch, I'll update accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You can add class propery to the particular `<a>` and directly select the particular attribute by their class name

Here's example:

HTML:

```
<div id="sideMenu">
    <li class="current_page_parent">
        <a class="notInULChildren" href="#">Category 1</a>
        <ul class="children">
            <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.notInULChildren{
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    background-color: #d6205c;
}
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/fmse0vuu/1/)